# Wrapping the application.name value with '@', what does it mean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

What does adding the '@' to name value of application.properties to the beginning and to the end mean?

I couldn't find usage of something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVEMF.png). I checked the Spring docs as well, but I couldn't find it. Is this usage a generic thing for programming or specific to application.properties of Spring?

Comment: It is a replacement token for maven. Maven will replace it with value for property named @propertyName@. Normaly you would use $, but this is reserved for SPEL in this context thus changed to @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-automatic-expansion)

> Rather than hardcoding some properties that are also specified in your
>   project’s build configuration, you can automatically expand them by
>   instead using the existing build configuration. This is possible in
>   both Maven and Gradle.

The format you mentioned is for Maven

> You can automatically expand properties from the Maven project by
>   using resource filtering. If you use the spring-boot-starter-parent,
>   you can then refer to your Maven ‘project properties’ with @..@
>   placeholders

**Update**

With [Spring Boot Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready) dependency added to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and

`info` endpoint [exposed](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints) (for http : `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info` )

a quick verification of this can be done.

Add the following property to pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <app.info.test>Test Value</app.info.test>
</properties>
```

and following entries in the application.properties file

```
info.app.name= Test App
info.app.java.source=1.8
info.app.test=@app.info.test@
```

Hitting http://localhost:8080/actuator/info will give the following response

```
{"app":{"name":"Test App","java":{"source":"1.8"},"test":"Test Value"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight Forward answer is the value which you store with **@name@** in application.properties are initialized when your project build start (based on same parameter name you pass with command).

It's used when you want to pass value of that variable at time of build

or value which are different based on environment.If you don't do that then it value becomes fixed.

when you're want to pass some parameter which are constant or repetitively use in your application like mail configuration or AWS configuration, version or etc. that things define in application.properties file.